# Java compiler and §(alt+21)

Tags: java

I am facing strange issue here. I am trying to use the character § (alt+21) as a delimiter. But when the source is compiled I see that in the class file this character appears as a character similar to a rectangle []. This is failing my tokenisation. Has someone see this before?

```
String dtr = "abcd§pqrs";   
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(templateDetails,"§");
```

in the compiled class file i see the below:

```
 String dtr = "abcd[]pqrs";   
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(templateDetails,"[]");
```

How do I resolve this? TIA

Comment: Did you tell your compiler about your source file encoding?

Comment: Do you actually see a opening and closing square bracket, or is it one character that is a box?  If the latter is true, you most likely need to set your compiler's encoding.

Comment: It is working on my Win7 and with JDK_1.6.30. The class file has `\247`

Comment: which java editor are you using

Comment: @vulcan it is just one charater that i see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `\u####` syntax to specify a character constant with a specific Unicode number.

This will allow you to specify it in pure ASCII without having to mess with file encodings and compiler behavior.

Comment: This is a workable solution, but I'd *still* suggest "messing" with the proper encoding: There's no reason to avoid using a sane character encoding these days (specifically UTF-8)

Comment: @JoachimSauer I've been bitten _enough_ by character encoding problems that we've standardized on the ASCII encoding in all our Maven projects.  Anyone saying "just remember to do X, Y and Z on all machines" is just waiting for a disaster to happen.

Comment: I've been bitten enough by those problems that we've standardized on UTF-8 encoding in all our projects ;-) It *is* possible to make your build not depend on the environment, if done correctly. But I understand where you're coming from.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Thanks for inputs, i decided not to mess with file encodings anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Change your editor encoding setting to UTF-8. Here is [How to do it for Eclipse](http://www.martinahrer.at/2007/06/03/eclipse-encoding-settings/)

Answer (score -1):

Probably your environment is not accepting that character.
You may update your compiler and check it again.